# Create a union type from an object key in an array

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript function `transformRow`

```js
type Row = {
  fields: { 
    name: string,
    value: unknown
  }[]
}

function transformRow<T extends Row>(row: T) {
  let result = new Map();
  for (let field of row.fields) {
    result.set(field.name, field.value)
  }

  return Object.fromEntries(result)
}
```

I want to be able to type the `result` returned from `transformRow` correctly, for example:

```js
const record = {
  fields: [
    { name: 'year', value: 1992 },
    { name: 'name', value: 'Jim' },
    { name: 'location', value: 'The moon' }
  ]
}

let row = transformRow(record);

/*
typeof row = {
  name: unknown
  age: unknown
  location: unknown
}
*/
```

Everything I do results in the union type of the field names being a `string` and not `"name" | "age" | "location"`.

Comment: Considering `name` is defined as `string` how could the union type of field names be anything but `string`? Are you expecting TypeScript, which only deals with compile-time types, to know what your runtime values are? Because I could pass a `Row` that is `{ fields: [] }`...

Comment: Why do you say "`as const` does not work when the record is an argument in a function"? I mean, [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mp0Dpm) shows using `as const` and I think the output is the type you want.  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hmm @jcalz that actually works exactly as I need. Feel free to write it up as an answer and I will mark it as such. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the question to remove the sentence about `as const`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for that to possibly work, you'll need your `record` variable to keep track of the particular [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `name` properties of the `fields` array.  Otherwise it's just going to be `string` and your `transformRow` will be of some type like `{[k: string]: unknown}`, which is too wide for your purposes.

The easiest way to do that is to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on the object literal initializer, which will tell the compiler to preserve as much specific information as it can:

```
const record = {
    fields: [
        { name: 'year', value: 1992 },
        { name: 'name', value: 'Jim' },
        { name: 'location', value: 'The moon' }
    ]
} as const;
```

which produces the type

```
/* const record: {
    readonly fields: readonly [{
        readonly name: "year";
        readonly value: 1992;
    }, {
        readonly name: "name";
        readonly value: "Jim";
    }, {
        readonly name: "location";
        readonly value: "The moon";
    }];
} */
```

which knows about `year`, `name`, and `location`, as required.

---

As for `transformRow()`, I'd be inclined to give it the following typing:

```
type Field = { name: string, value: unknown }

function transformRow<T extends Field>(
    row: { fields: readonly T[] }
) {
    let result = new Map();
    for (let field of row.fields) {
        result.set(field.name, field.value)
    }
    return Object.fromEntries(result) as
        { [U in T as U['name']]: U['value'] }
}
```

Here I'm making the function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `T`, the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of element types of the `fields` array.  This is the most direct way to represent the types you care about, instead of making it generic in something like `R extends Row` and then extracting the relevant type via something like `R["fields"][number]`.

Okay, `T` is a union of `Field`-subtypes, like `{name: "foo", value: number} | {name: "bar", value: string}`.  We can convert that to an object type by [using key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as).  The type `{[U in T as U['name']]: U['value']}` is an object type that iterates over each member `U` of the `T` union, and produces a property with key `U["name"]` and value `U["value"]`, like `{foo: number; bar: string}`.

It's unfortunately beyond the compiler's type checking abilities to verify that the implementation actually returns a value of that remapped type given its inputs.  The compiler sees `Object.fromEntries(result)` as of type `any` and there's no point in trying to have it figure out the right type.  Instead, I just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) `Object.fromEntries(result) as {[U in ⋯]: ⋯};` to tell it what type to return.  Type assertions shift the type checking burden away from the compiler and onto the developer, so we should be careful that we've asserted the right thing.

---

Okay, let's test it:

```
let row = transformRow(record);

/*
let row: {
    year: 1992;
    name: "Jim";
    location: "The moon";
}
*/

console.log(row);
/* {
  "year": 1992,
  "name": "Jim",
  "location": "The moon"
}  */
```

Looks good, that's about as specific a type as one can hope for, and the value matches the type.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEygXigbygOwIYC2EAXFAM7ABOcOA5gDRQBueiAriVGzgNY4D2AdxxQAvgFgAUFIBm3AMbA4-EVTw4yM-pQIAlIQB4AKlAgAPYBBzIysBCgB8ACilQ3USkNLYZ9m6UoIPGQVRBAoIwBtAF0xKQBKLFd3RAhgDwgyNkR0jBwIQSgAWTwwJ3iAbmS3LUooJ1T03yRUfhkPIQA6ZpQyRMxq9zdArJzOsjSnHuRO-CJGac6Wdgh4wYlJIcDgNkoRAHkAIwArCEVuzwIAURwqBDInEezgRLwyQaHsSIBVKBoIqBvKDfSIAcjmEFB0WipBBoOWHChcUkGyk8hUFAy6MoqAwA027mmZFIkQ+7mwENIoJAQUooMYCM4AEYAJwsgBMYnoZLcFMInHB-PpzFYHCpACk4ARQVyeVhcPyqYh+PI8EoVMLGVSjAALaAEfga5FDaJSUSA2zojTAKqSAD0ACooFbMYFschvINAsFQuEiQEgiEcGEoJF8UMtoHfQqiKQAEQ0vCUOO2iPub1BkNaqCsjmp9yiRjhtMZH3B8KUqBxiEpuUZ6PZuOSgi1gluQtJNsR+vlmOcOPK1XqnCtkulzPhRu6-WGkf59vRW3mh12qRSRodQoYNQaWp6ISPM7aZCVNf2h3rtKbz1dxOUUi59nzvvx5ujlIqtXKHDx6dQA0qK2GwrmeLr8KknTKrQjxCKe56dm4Ca0nGD5suy3IEtW-IoVWb4YYhg5foBv56v+s5xmabggZIQA)